# Value stuck in excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with one macro that I run.
I use it to read another excel file in a subfolder and build a report based on that.

This macro is being used every day and almost every month ago some file name stuck as a value of a file name and fails in the end with the next message.

Here an error message:

[image]

Value keeps here for some reason:

[image]

In a working subfolder, I see no hidden temp file with that name. This temp file mentioned in the error message not even found on the PC(though that might be in some temp folders)

The issue looks simple but I cannot find a solution for that.

I have a feeling that it more related not to Macro but to some temp data of excel.

Would be glad to here any ideas about that.

Comment: Could you please include the relevant parts of your code as text?

Comment: [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). • Well you add all files that end with `xlsx` to your file list. That also adds the temporary files. So exclude any files that start with `~$` from that list and you don't have those issues.

Comment: I do not think that it's about code. It was working for more than 6 months. Maybe some MSO update did some SEC changes or else.

I tried to change the folder name and now I get a different error "Run-time error 40351" "Method 'Run' for object '_Application' failed"

Answer (score 0):

It probably is some temp file by the looks of things.

Can you not just do this?

```
If Left(FileName, 2) <> "~$" then
    'Do stuff
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found that Trust center settings for Access and Excel got some refusive settings. Looks like some Security update did that.

Allowed my locations in both apps and now it works.